# Database update not working inside Meteor method

Tags: meteor

I have a template event that allows the user to insert content into a collection in the Meteor database.

```
var challenge_info = {
        "creator_id": Meteor.userId(),
        "creator_firstname": creat_firstname,
        "creator_avatarurl": Session.get('chUser').avatar_url,
        "recepient_id": recepient_id,
        "recepient_firstname": recepient_firstname,
        "recepient_avatarurl": recepient_avatarurl,
        ...
        "state": 0
    };

    Meteor.call('insertChallenge', challenge_info);

    Meteor.call('incrementStatistic', Meteor.userId(),'c_sent');
    Meteor.call('incrementStatistic', recepient_id,'c_pending');

    Session.set('new_challenge_reset', true);

    Router.go('home');
```

Everything is working okay when calling the Method 'insertChallenge', that just calls ChallengesList.insert(challenge_info).

But when trying to call the 'incrementStatistic' method, nothing happens. Terminal does not give me any errors, and I'm not able to test the query on the browser console (updating the database from the client side without the selection being the ID is not possible anymore in Meteor and I have autopublish removed).

Here are the methods (inside Meteor.methods()):

```
incrementStatistic : function(user_id, stat){
    UserStatistics.update({"user_id": user_id}, {"$inc" : {stat: 1}});
},
decrementStatistic : function(user_id, stat){
    UserStatistics.update({"user_id": user_id}, {"$inc" : {stat: 1}});
},
createStatistics : function(){
    UserStatistics.insert({'user_id': Meteor.userId(), 'c_won': 0, 'c_lost': 0, 'c_accepted': 0 , 'c_rejected': 0, 'c_pending': 0, 'c_sent': 0});
    return true;
}
```

I'm able to retrieve the collection information (in another template), using `UserStatistics.findOne({"user_id": Meteor.userId()});`, but the increment never works.

Although it may not have to do with this issue, I also have a server method that uses the Collection.update() that works just fine (although it uses `_id` as selector):

```
updateChallengeState: function(challenge_id, new_challenge_state){
    ChallengesList.update({_id: challenge_id}, {"$set" : {"state": new_challenge_state}});
}
```

Anyone have any clue about what is possibly happening?

Comment: are you sure server methods are called and user record in userstatistics exists before updating?

Comment: What exactly is not working? If you can retrieve the user data in a different template and the data is correct then those `incrementStatistic` calls are updating the database. Are you having an issue with your template not updating? Perhaps you need to show your template html and helpers as well.

Comment: @Sasikanth, yes. I use the 'createStatistics' method to create the record when a new account is created, and the record exists and gets well populated.

Comment: @MichelFloyd, I guess what's not working is the UserStatistics.update() inside the 'incrementStatistic' method on server.js.
The other template is able to get the information from the collection but the icrement does not work  (it gives me the object created with the 'createStatistics' method) and then display it within the template with the helpers that were created (basically UserStatistics.find( )).
There is no other code interfering with my explanation above.

Comment: Is the `stat` field being published by the server? Have you looked in the mongo console to see if the data is being written at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to not have defined the `user_id` variable passed in those methods (`incrementStatistic` and `decrementStatistic`).

Instead, as you do in the `createStatistics` method, just pass `Meteor.userId()`, and I believe you don't need to send the `stat` either:

```
incrementStatistic : function(){
    UserStatistics.update({user_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$inc : {stat: 1}});
},
decrementStatistic : function(){
    UserStatistics.update({user_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$inc : {stat: 1}});
},
```

And call the methods without any parameter:

```
Meteor.call('incrementStatistic');
```

By the way, I recommend you adopt one way of using the mongodb syntax. At times you seem to use apostrophes ('user_id'), at times quotes ("user_id"), and at times neither of them (user_id). For the field names, it is optional to use them, but for the operators($inc, $set, $and, $or etc.) it's standard to not use quotes or apostrophes. Refer to [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/crud-introduction/).